# Missing a return statement error

Tags: java, return

I've written a code and whenever I try to test it out, I get a error saying:

```
"StreetAddress.java:62: missing return statement 

 }"
```

Here is the code:

```
public class StreetAddress
  {
     private String myStreet;
     private String myCity;
     private String myState;
     private String myZip;

 public StreetAddress( String street, String city, String state, String zip )
 {
  myStreet = street;
  myCity = city;
  myState = state;
  myZip = zip;
 }

 public void setStreet( String street )
{
 myStreet = street;
}

 public String getStreet()
{
 return myStreet;
}

 public void setCity( String city )
{
 myCity = city;
}

 public String getCity()
{
 return myCity;
}

 public void setState( String state )
{
 myState = state;
}

 public String getState()
{
 return myState;
}

 public void setZIP( String zip )
{
 myZip = zip;
}

 public String getZIP()
{
 return myZip;
}

public String mailingLabel()
{
 System.out.println( getStreet() );
 System.out.println( getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP() );
}
}
}
```

I have no idea where a } is missing Ive checked my code several times. Please help!

Comment: A `}` is something entirely different from a `return` statement. This may be the source of your confusion.

Comment: You have a method without a return statement whose signature says it returns something. Where's the mystery?

Comment: Which line is line 62?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This function:

```
public String mailingLabel()
{
 System.out.println( getStreet() );
 System.out.println( getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP() );
}
```

is declared to return a string but is missing a return statement. Either make it void or return something - whichever was the intention.

Comment: My problem is I want the method mailingLabel to use an instance to return the instance.getStreet() and blah blah but I dont know how to implement that in the code. What's another way I can use it so that the compiler knows that its asking me to apply that to the instance?

Comment: @Rohan: It *does* know to apply it to the instance because the function is not static. Just write `return getStreet();`

Comment: Also, why not avoid the extra function call while you're in the same class and just do `return myStreet` ? Please tell me you're at least using eclipse to write Java code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public String mailingLabel()
{
 System.out.println( getStreet() );
 System.out.println( getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP() );
}
```

In the above method, you are supposed to return a String as per signature of the method, but you are not returning the String.

2 options:

A. Keeping method signature same, return the String:

```
public String mailingLabel()
{
 return getStreet() + getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP();
}
```

OR

B. Change the method signature:

```
public void mailingLabel()
{
 System.out.println( getStreet() );
 System.out.println( getCity() + ", " + getState() + " " + getZIP() );
}
```